# AES Encryption in C# and Decryption using CryptoJS.js

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption

I'm trying to create in encryption in C# where the decryption will be in javascript. (CryptoJS)

I'm running .net 4.5 framework

Here is the sample code in javascript for decryption

```
var sample = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, secret);

var decryptedText = sample.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Comment: Is the JavaScript-code changeable? Is `secret` a string or a `WordArray`? Since the key and IV are not specified separately, `secret` is probably a string. A string is interpreted as a passphrase and the key and IV are derived from it, [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input). Thus, the C#-code would be quite complex, since the derivation logic (logic of the OpenSSL-method `EVP_BytesToKey`) would also have to be available in the C#-code. Therefore, it would be much easier if key and IV were specified directly (both as `WordArray`) instead of the passphrase during decryption.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://yogeshpansare.wordpress.com/2014/07/14/aes-256-encryptingdecrypting-data-in-c-that-is-encrypteddecrypted-using-cryptojs/).

Comment: Hi @Topaco the secret is just a string.

Comment: Hi @MasLoo, the link you sent works for me. Thank you so much!